# Passing parameters in redirection, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am redirecting from one action "receive" to other "show" using

`redirect_to @post`

I need to know if the visitor was redirected in the view for show

Can I store a variable @flag in receive and use it in "show" after the redirect? I couldn't.

Is there a way to pass a parameter without showing it in the URL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should store it in the `session`, maybe something like this in your `receive` action:

```
session[:redirected_from_receive] = true
```

Be sure to set this to `false` or `nil` in the `show` action. Alternatively, you can check the `request.referer` environment variable to see if it matches your `receive` page URL, but this is perhaps less reliable than using the session.

Answer (score 2):

Use session/cookies for passing parameters without showing them in URLs. You could probably also hack the `flash` object and pass a custom key before redirecting:

```
flash[:from] = 'receive'
redirect_to @post
```